# Select the users who have one entry in the table, and the entry has type = "402"

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table, where users have 0 or more requests. Each request have one type.

```
id
user_id
type
```

What I want to do is to get the users who only have one request, and the request is of type "402".
For example if a user has one "402" and one "403", I don't want to select him.

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(type) = 1 AND type = "402"
```

But it didn't work (I got results from users who had several requests, but only one "402", like in my example above).

Any guesses ? ;)

Comment: What means `But it didn't work`? Any error? Please add sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table where type = '402' 
GROUP BY type HAVING COUNT(type) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
select t1.* from table t1 where t1.type = '402'
and not exists(
 select 1 from table t2 
 where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
 and t2.type <> '402'
)
```